# Create material design button via code

Tags: java, android, material-design

I'm trying to create material design buttons programmatically. (not via xml)

I'm trying to use the ButtonRectangle contractor and I get this error.

My code:

```
 AttributeSet attr = new AttributeSet() {
                    @Override
                    public int getAttributeCount() {
                        return 0;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String getAttributeName(int index) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String getAttributeValue(int index) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String getAttributeValue(String namespace, String name) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String getPositionDescription() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getAttributeNameResource(int index) {
                        return 0;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getAttributeListValue(String namespace, String attribute, String[] options, int defaultValue) {
                        return 0;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean getAttributeBooleanValue(String namespace, String attribute, boolean defaultValue) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getAttributeResourceValue(String namespace, String attribute, int defaultValue) {
                        return 0;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getAttributeIntValue(String namespace, String attribute, int defaultValue) {
                        return 0;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getAttributeUnsignedIntValue(String namespace, String attribute, int defaultValue) {
                        return 0;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public float getAttributeFloatValue(String namespace, String attribute, float defaultValue) {
                        return 0;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getAttributeListValue(int index, String[] options, int defaultValue) {
                        return 0;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean getAttributeBooleanValue(int index, boolean defaultValue) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getAttributeResourceValue(int index, int defaultValue) {
                        return 0;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getAttributeIntValue(int index, int defaultValue) {
                        return 0;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getAttributeUnsignedIntValue(int index, int defaultValue) {
                        return 0;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public float getAttributeFloatValue(int index, float defaultValue) {
                        return 0;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String getIdAttribute() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String getClassAttribute() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getIdAttributeResourceValue(int defaultValue) {
                        return 0;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getStyleAttribute() {
                        return 0;
                    }
                };

                Context c = getApplicationContext();
                ButtonRectangle btn = new ButtonRectangle(c, attr);
```

But I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: maakesher.com.black.maakesher.psychoQuizzesActivity$1$1 cannot be cast to android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you define the app theme as appcompat material design, you just create a new button like: `Button b = new Button(c);` and add it to a container (layout)

Comment: Can you explain where do I do such a thing? (I'm a bit new at Android, came from iOS).

Comment: I did, I know how to add a button programmatically, just this button not getting the params that a regular button gets.

Comment: Change apptheme in styles.xml and use AppCompat to get material design on pre-lollipop devices